# How to get desired output using Ansible jinja2 if else statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Below is tasK:

```
            - name: primary slot on active
              debug: msg={{slotid.stdout_lines}}
              register: slotidoutput
```

output1:

```
TASK [primary slot on active] *************************************************************************
ok: [1.1.1.1] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "Primary Slot ID         1"
        ]
    ]
}
```

some devices dosen't have primary slot ID so at that time output will be like :

output2:

```
TASK [primary slot on active] ***********************************************************************
ok: [2.2.2.2] => {
    "msg": []
}
```

so i am working on a jinja2 template

```
                       {% if 'Primary Slot ID' in slotidoutput %}
                        {{slotidoutput.msg[0][0]}}
                       {% else %}
                        Single Slot
                       {% endif %}
```

i am always getting value as "Single Slot" even though i ran on multi slot device which has output1

```
Single Slot
```

desired print value for device 1.1.1.1 is:

```
Primary Slot ID         1
```

desired print value for device 2.2.2.2 is:

```
Single Slot
```

I am sure that i am doing some mistake in jinja if else statement. Can some one check and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few conditions that we need to address for the template to work properly.

- sometimes `slotid.stdout_lines` is a nested list
- in some cases it is an empty list `[]`
- conditional check with `in` will perform exact match on list items, and search match on a string

Also, `register` on debug output seems unnecessary as it holds the same data structure as `slotid.stdout_lines`.

So tasks and template such as below should address the above issues:

Tasks:

```yaml
  # Flatten nested list to single level
    - set_fact:
        slotidout: "{{ slotid.stdout_lines|flatten }}"
  # Using random name for template
    - template:
        src: testtemplate.j2
        dest: /tmp/testtemplate
```

Template `testtemplate.j2`:

```
{% if slotidout[0] is defined %}
  {% if "Primary" in slotidout[0] %}
  {{ slotidout[0] }}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
Single slot
{% endif %}
```

This should create the file with appropriate values based on conditions. You may adjust the conditions based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you seshadri_c worked like a charm.